# Healpy and the 4D Sphere - how to use pix2ang to create the 3 arrays of angles (ksi, theta, phi)?

Tags: healpy, 4d

I am working with hyperspheres and would like to use healpy to create the three angles 
ksi, theta, phi for a nside hypersphere.

How do I do that considering that these are the four coordinates of this hypersphere:

```
u1=sin(ksi)sin(theta)cos(phi)
u2=sin(ksi)sin(theta)sin(phi)
u3=sin(ksi)cos(theta)
u4=cos(ksi)
```

Thanks,

Marco